# Flutter Emulator issues

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, setuptools, licensing

[Screen of death; my version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewDs2.jpg)

I have 4 problems with this screen
1.) I have absolutely downloaded all the requirements
2.) my phone is on developer mode and connected to my laptop but isn't being read
3.) I can't create emulators in android studio
4.) I have added the paths to my env variables...

I'm running on an aspire one of with 2gb Ram...

what do I do different with these same PC specs to get coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well First Of All Enable USB Debugging In Your Phone And See if It Shows Your Device Now.

Now In You Your Command Line Run This

**flutter doctor --android --licenses**

It will automatically install all the required License And You Are Good to go

AS for CommandLine Tools error Navigate to SDK Folder in your Command by entering

**cd "Path of your sdk"**

and After That hit this line

**"--install cmdline-tools;latest"**

I repeat navigate to your sdk folder and then hit this command and you are good to go.

And personally I won't suggest you to install the emulator as you said your ram is of 2gb Then it will Lag alot better turn on usb Debugging and try it on your phone !!

Comment: after enabling usb debugging bit still isn't showing my device.

Comment: my android version is 7, do you think that is a negative factor? also whatvsdk path, is it the flutter SDK path? thanks for your answers ⭐

Comment: Did You Get Your Android Studio Working?

Comment: thanks for the help... but OS crashed

Comment: i can't even flash the hard drive